# Permissions in a shared server (chmod)

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have recently been given an account on a Linux server. This server is shared with different members of a research institution and the standard permissions allow other users to access my directories and files.

I have decided to create a folder (let's call it `private`) in my home and to change the permissions with `chmod 700 ~/private`. I have noticed that the permissions of new files created in `private` might allow others to access them. I am fairly new with `chmod` and I don't understand whether having set the permissions of `private` as above prevent others to view and access what is within this folder, regardless of the files permissions.

Shall I use a similar approach as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu#_=_) to set the permissions of all files within `private` or having set the permissions of this folder is already enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already enough. The directory access limitations take precedence over its content's permissions.